# How to use without function with helm (go) templating?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am using helm to deploy namespaces on our kubernetes clusters.

**This is the template:**

```
{{- range $namespaces := .Values.namespaces }}
{{- if ne $namespaces.name "default" }}    
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: {{ $namespaces.name }}
  labels:
    name: {{ $namespaces.name }}
{{- end }}
```

**The values file:**

```
namespaces:
  - name: default
  - name: ingress-controller
  - name: rbac-manager
  - name: velero
  - name: test1
  - name: test2
  - name: test3
```

This works fine, but now I want to set a specific label for certain namespaces. default, ingress-controller, rbac-manager and velero are namespaces I don't want to set the label for, but only for team specific namespaces.. in this case test{1,2,3}. But these variable. 
So instead of using the has function:

```
{{ if has .Values.favorite.drink (list "coffee" "thee" "milk") }}mug: true{{ end }}
```

I would like to use the without function, but I am doing something wrong so hopefull someone can help me out with this one:

```
{{- range $namespaces := .Values.namespaces }}
{{- if ne $namespaces.name "default" }}    
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: {{ $namespaces.name }}
  labels:
    name: {{ $namespaces.name }}
{{ $custom := without $namespaces.name "default" "ingress-controller" "rbac-manager" "velero" }}
{{- if eq $custom.name }}
    namespace: custom
{{- end }}
---
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

When I run this I get error:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: template: namespaces/templates/namespaces.yaml:10:14: executing "namespaces/templates/namespaces.yaml" at <without $namespaces.name "default" "ingress-controller" "rbac-manager" "velero">: error calling without: Cannot find without on type string
```

I get the same error when I use:

```
{{- range $namespaces := .Values.namespaces }}
{{- if ne $namespaces.name "default" }}    
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: {{ $namespaces.name }}
  labels:
    name: {{ $namespaces.name }}
{{ $custom := without $namespaces.name (list "default" "ingress-controller" "rbac-manager" "velero") }}
{{- if eq $custom.name }}
    namespace: custom
{{- end }}
---
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not really an answer on getting it to work with the without function, but I got it work with this:

```
{{ range $namespaces := .Values.namespaces }}
{{ if ne $namespaces.name "default" }}    
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: {{ $namespaces.name }}
  labels:
    name: {{ $namespaces.name }}
{{ if (not (has $namespaces.name (list "default" "ingress-controller" "rbac-manager" "velero"))) }}
    namespace: custom
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a string as a first parameter to [without function](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/lists.html), while it requires a list.

Here's an example on how you can do it with `without` function. I removed redundant `name` key from `namespaces` array though.

**values.yaml**

```
namespaces:
  - default
  - ingress-controller
  - rbac-manager
  - velero
  - test1
  - test2
  - test3
```

**namespace.yaml**

```
{{ $compare := without .Values.namespaces list "default" "ingress-controller" "rbac-manager" "velero" }}
{{- range $namespace := .Values.namespaces }}
{{- if ne $namespace "default" }}    
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: {{ $namespace }}
  labels:
    name: {{ $namespace }}
{{- if has $namespace $compare }}
    namespace: custom
{{- end }}
---
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

As `without`function is returning a *list*, first we create a *list* without specified values. Than we iterate over `namespaces` and check whether `$custom` list has the value or not.

Answer (score 0):

So the sprig docs are a bit lacking, but I wanted to say that you generally do **not** pass a list as the second argument. The **first** argument is definitely a list, but you can see in the [sprig unit tests for the list functions](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/94f67ecb189d4d9bfc757740537503e73a04012f/list_test.go#L273) that the next argument definitely is not, but just the element you want to skip. If you combine that information with the [official docs](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/lists.html), you could infer that you pass in additional arguments to skip additional elements in the array.

For example,

```golang
{{ without (list 1 2 3 4) 1 2 3 }}
```

would give `[4]`

If you really actually wanted to skip an element that is an entire list, then you could do this:

```golang
{{ without (list (list 1 2 3) 4) (list 1 2 3) }}
```

which would give you `[4]`.